# Freetype static linking undefined reference

Tags: c++, static-libraries, freetype

After downloading and compiling a static library from freetype source code using visual studio 2017, I've linked to my project using cmake under cygwin :

```
set ( FREETYPE_LIBRARY /home/User/pdfalto/freetype-2.9.1/objs/Win32/freetype.lib)
target_link_libraries(myproject ${FREETYPE_LIBRARY} dl)
```

this throws errors :

```
(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'
```

using nm to list the symbols gives :

```
$ nm /home/User/pdfalto/freetype-2.9.1/objs/Win32/freetype.lib | grep FT_Init_FreeType
00000000 T _FT_Init_FreeType
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you check in the project property that you have the link library? And are you trying to build 64bits or 32bits?

Comment: Oh, and mingw cannot read lib files created by VS.

Comment: Do you know how to compile static freetype using cygwin ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818585/freetype-not-compiling-on-windows-with-mingw